# Avoid select tag's value being reset to default when changing selected option values through React state

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a select tag where the options are determined by the React state and can change both in value and number. Whenever an option that isn't the default is selected and the state changes its value, the select tag resets to the default option (The first one).

I have tried adding unique keys that don't change based on the value to the option tag (a different thread suggested that).

```
...<option key={`unique-${index}`}>...
```

One idea I came up with is to have `UUID` or similar to the value of each option that doesn't change and a separate value like `display name` that can change freely. This would not be ideal, because we have other code that depends on the current setup.

Here's an example of the issue we have now on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0L2y57sk/17/).

The third option should be selected already (if not select it) and if you use the input to change its value you'll see that the select will switch to the first option.

In conclusion: Is there any way to keep the same selected value other than looping through the state and comparing and replacing the older values?

Edit:
I should point out that the example above is simplified. In the actual code, there are many similar `<select>` with different values. This makes it harder to simply loop through state and is also why I'm looking for an alternative.

Solution:

As the answer below shows, if the select is controlled, meaning it values is defined by the state, then of course state needs to be updated on change.

What I will do in the future is only use `<select>` as an uncontrolled element and let it manage its own value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mutating state in

```
  blurInput(value) {
    const newItems = [...this.state.items];
    newItems[2].value = value; // not immutable
    this.setState({
        items: newItems
    });
  }
```

You have to change it to:

```
  blurInput(value) {
    const items = [...this.state.items];
    const selected = this.state.selected === items[2].value
      ? value
      : this.state.selected;
    items[2] = {...items[2], value};
    this.setState({
        items,
        selected
    });
  }
```

Comment: Good point on the immutable. However, the reason your code works is that you modify `selected` manually. I may not have been clear in my question, but comparing the old and new values is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: It's not comparing the old to new values. The "const selected" part handles the situation when you have selected the third option and updating it's value. It ensures that the third option remains selected.

Comment: You can about it if it's not included in your scope

Comment: Right, sorry. It's comparing to see if `selected` had the old value before the change. I guess since the `select` is controlled by state there's no way to have it update without manually updating the state